# New theme type in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I want to use `Keycloak` to secure a `Java Spring` application and I can't find resources if you are able to create a new view (theme type), not customize an existing one, and add it to `keycloak` customizable themes types.

Answer (score 0):

You can created themes for keycloak from scratch and there are some themes you can download as well, just search the web.

As for the spring part, the way this is done is read the client cookies/headers on each request and call the keycloak API to validate them. Or you can use a library than can do this for you, in my first project with keycloak I followed [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) and it worked fine.